# jQuery's toggleClass and order of class names in .css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**BACKGROUND:**

I have text with an arrow pointing to the right, clicking on the text/arrow reveals a div and substitutes the arrowRight with arrowDown.

**PROBLEM:**

The problem stems from the fact that my code works depending upon the order in the .css file and I don't know why that should matter w jQuery.

**CSS:**

```
.arrow{display:inline-block;  width:15px; height:10px;background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.arrowRight{background-image:url("../graphics/triangleRight.gif"); }
.arrowDown{ background-image: url("../graphics/triangleDown.gif");}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="showListOfBids" class="align-c">
     List of Bids <div class="arrow arrowRight">
</div>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$("#showListOfBids").click(function(){
   $(".bidList").toggleClass("show");
   $(".arrowRight").toggleClass("arrowDown");
});
```

**Developer Tool > Elements**

Toggling adds and removes arrowDown

Toggle Off:

```
<div class="arrow arrowRight"></div>
```

Toggle On:

```
<div class="arrow arrowRight arrowDown"></div>
```

**QUESTION:** Why does the order of the class .arrowDown affect the display? AFAIK the css file isn't being reparsed when using jQuery. jQuery adds the class to the DOM and the parser just searches for that one element.

**COMMENT:** I don't like toggling doubling up on the classes.  Am I using it incorrectly? I was using removeClass and addClass and changed over to toggleClass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the order of the class .arrowDown affect the display?

Because that's how CSS works. If there are two rules that have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the one that appears later in the file wins.

In your case, both `.arrowRight` and `.arrowDown` have the same specificity. If there is an element with both of these classes, `.arrowDown` wins. If you switch the rules, `.arrowRight` would win.

> AFAIK the css file isn't being reparsed when using jQuery. jQuery adds the class to the DOM and the parser just searches for that one element.

You are right, it has nothing to do with jQuery. The browser only sees which classes the element has and applies the rules for them.

---

So, the order of CSS rules matter and that has nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery. Consider it a "feature".

Answer (score 2):

Because you have written arrowDown image at last:

And having both classes i.e. arrowRight and arrowDown, the last would take place.

> <s>.arrowRight{background-image:url("../graphics/triangleRight.gif"); }</s>
>
> .arrowDown{ background-image: url("../graphics/triangleDown.gif");}

---

To go correctly with that use toggle like this:

```
$(".arrowRight").toggleClass("arrowRight arrowDown");
```

Which makes you sure that there is only one arrow: arrowRight or arrowDown

Comment: But - and here's where I getting confused / getting things wrong: in the HTML it goes class="arrow arrowRight arrowDown" shouldn't the placement in the HTML/DOM supercede the order in the css file?

Comment: @Mayo: That's just not how it works. The order in the HTML attribute is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mayo In html, you should put only one of them arrowRight or arrowDown but not both for initial setting.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks. I knew I wasn't reading things correctly and wanted to get a grasp on what I was missing.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - that toggleClass solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Every CSS rule has some weight for browser. For example you have this CSS

```
a.colored { color: violet;}
.colored { color: orange;}
div a {color: green;}
a {color: red:}
```

and this HTML

```
<div><a class="colored" href="example.html">Test link</a></div>
```

The color of link will be violet because the rule for `a.colored` is most specific (it has a class defined) and has more weight than the other rules so it will be applied last. You can read more detailed explanation [here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

In your example you have two rules of the same weight. So the browser just applies them in order they are in CSS-file. `.arrowRight` is applied first, `.arrowDown` is applied second.

The important thing here that only position in CSS file matters, not order of classes in `class` attribute of a tag.

Comment: Interestingly enough - I thought that didn't apply with jquery toggleClass as it wasn't reparsing the entire css file hence order didn't matter. If one removes a class and then adds a class the order in the css ought not matter. I need to rethink how I use toggleClass.